# Am I supposed to put all .o files in the library?

Tags: c++, g++, static-libraries

I want to create a library that lets my programs to use one class, lets call it A, which has some neat methods and so on... This class, though, relies on a few others (B and C), and it includes their `.hpp` files in its `.cpp` file.

The build process goes like this:

```
g++ -c B.cpp
g++ -c C.cpp
g++ -c A.cpp

ar rvs A.a *.o
```

By doing this, my other projects now only need to files to include my A class, `A.hpp` and `A.a`. Am I making a static library correctly? Should I only put A.o in the archive (library) (doing so produces errors)?

Just for reference, this is how a program using the A class is compiled:

```
g++ test1.cpp A.a -o test1
```

**Edit:** is there a way to implicitly tell the linker to link my program with A.a? Just like I don't manually need to link it with iostream...

Comment: Is it working the way you do it now?

Comment: As long as you put the library after the object files that use it, you should be fine.  Put the library first and the linker will fail to find the symbols defined in the library (because it didn't know it needed to look for those symbols when it scanned the library).

Comment: @KerrekSB, yes, it does. And please all, see the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fine how you're doing it now. Put all the object files into the static library.